# unable to compute 8 digit 'double' variable

Tags: java, double

This is a simple example of my problem. I cant store a double variable with more than 8 digits in it. I have provided the out put at the end. I am doing my project in netbeans 6.9 and jdk 1.6. (I am using windows 8.1 x64, if these information's matter). Please reply fast as possible.

```
class DoubleT
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  double x=1000000;
  int y=0;
  while(y<20)
  {
   x=x+x;
   System.out.println("output: "+x);
   y++;
  }
 }
}


output: 2000000.0
output: 4000000.0
output: 8000000.0
output: 1.6E7
output: 3.2E7
output: 6.4E7
output: 1.28E8
output: 2.56E8
output: 5.12E8
output: 1.024E9
output: 2.048E9
output: 4.096E9
output: 8.192E9
output: 1.6384E10
output: 3.2768E10
output: 6.5536E10
output: 1.31072E11
output: 2.62144E11
output: 5.24288E11
output: 1.048576E12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("output: %f\n", x);
```

The above code can be used to print a decimal number in place of scientific notation, If you do not want decimal part use `%.0f`. [Documentation for `printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)

Comment: ok.. i am just a beginner here.. don't know that much about these.. sorry. i have only used the above code from u in 'C'